# Send form details as an email

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I'm writing an LWC record edir form that is based on a contact record. and here is my code.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Contact"
        onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-output-field field-name="AccountId">
        </lightning-output-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Email">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Here, instead of submitting the form, I want to send the form details as an email to a user. I've got the email code ready with me. Help I need is how can I print the above form values using `console.log` in a `Name`-`Value` format?

below is my `JS`.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class GetyDatarecord extends LightningElement {
    recordId = 'myContactId';

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const inputFields = this.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
        if (inputFields) {
            inputFields.forEach(field => {
                console.log(`${field.Name} - ${field.value}`);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add `onsubmit=""` attribute to your submit `lightning-button` in your html file to specify event handlers.

```
 <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" onsubmit={handleSubmit} name="update" label="Update">
```

Second, replace `this.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');` with `this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');` and then print the FieldName and its value in a `Name-Value` format using `console.log(field.fieldName + ' - ' + field.value);` in your js `handleSubmit(event)` function.

Below is the code example:

```
   handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
    if (inputFields) {
        inputFields.forEach(field => {
            console.log(field.fieldName + ' - ' + field.value);
        });
    }
}
```

You can read more about `lightning-record-edit-form` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation)

Comment: I see `onsubmit` already provided at form level and the button type is `submit`. Just curious, any specific reason to move it at button level. I see only two issues in the `code` from the the question. First, as you pointed, out the element name should be fetched using `lightning-input-field` through `this.template. querySelectorAll`,  second `Name` should be replaced with `fieldName` like, `console.log(${field. fieldName} - ${field.value});`

Comment: Hi Hemant, It is clearly mention in the [document][1] 

"To customize the behavior of your form when data is submitted, use the  onsubmit attribute to specify event handlers. If you capture the submit event and submit the form programmatically, use event.preventDefault() to cancel the default behavior of the event. This prevents a duplicate form submission."


  [1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation

Comment: Thanks for the details, I missed that part :)

Comment: Thanks @ShagunSharma, it worked. I needed to replace your `button` code with mine as `<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" onclick={handleSubmit} name="update" label="Update"> </lightning-button>`.

Comment: and this is placed outside of the form

Comment: @user3872094 Always happy to help :))